# Devexpress generate trash in the source code

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I'm using VS10. I'm edit the code on the aspx-page there is no any unexpected events but if I do anything on the tab Constructor then DevExpress creates many of code. I'm in despair. How is it turned off?

**Tab Source code**

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnFindServer" runat="server" Text="Find" Width="100%" />
```

**I do something on the Constructor Tab**

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnFindServer" runat="server" Text="Find">
<Image Align="NotSet">
</Image>
<CheckedStyle>
    <BackgroundImage Repeat="Repeat" />
    <Border BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderLeft BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderTop BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderRight BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderBottom BorderStyle="NotSet" />
</CheckedStyle>
<PressedStyle>
    <BackgroundImage Repeat="Repeat" />
    <Border BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderLeft BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderTop BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderRight BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderBottom BorderStyle="NotSet" />
</PressedStyle>
<HoverStyle>
    <BackgroundImage Repeat="Repeat" />
    <Border BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderLeft BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderTop BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderRight BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderBottom BorderStyle="NotSet" />
</HoverStyle>
<FocusRectBorder BorderStyle="NotSet" />
<BackgroundImage Repeat="Repeat" />
<Border BorderStyle="NotSet" />
<BorderLeft BorderStyle="NotSet" />
<BorderTop BorderStyle="NotSet" />
<BorderRight BorderStyle="NotSet" />
<BorderBottom BorderStyle="NotSet" />
<DisabledStyle>
    <BackgroundImage Repeat="Repeat" />
    <Border BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderLeft BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderTop BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderRight BorderStyle="NotSet" />
    <BorderBottom BorderStyle="NotSet" />
</DisabledStyle>
```

Comment: It's not "trash" as such, rather designer-generated mark-up. Presumably you just want to get rid of it to keep the mark-up "tidy"?

Comment: Yes, I don't want that devexpress made a html code in design time.

Answer (score 0):

If you did these modifications in the Design View, so it is not HTML.

It is how the designer modifications are serialized to the Source View:

[Web Forms Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zzhfb89h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)